# How do i overload operator "[]" for vector containing my own class objects

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

So i got a class WayPoint (inside the namespace HHN).
And i got a class WayPointContainer. 
The container got a private vector variable to store objects from the type "HHN::WayPoint"

What i want to do now is i want to overload the operator[] so i can
easy access the objects inside the vector like so:

```
WayPoint p1("name",1.5,2.0);
WayPointContainer c1; 
c1[0] = p1          // This would add the WayPoint p1 to the vector of the container on index 0
WayPoint p2 = c1[0] // This would get the WayPoint from the vector at index 0 and copy it to p2
```

...

I found different implementations but they were for other types then vector or did not use a complex type inside the vector.

Here is my WayPointContainer.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "WayPoint.h"

#ifndef SRC_WAYPOINTCONTAINER_H_
#define SRC_WAYPOINTCONTAINER_H_

class WayPointContainer {
    private:
        std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>* pContainer{ nullptr };

    public:
        WayPointContainer();
        WayPointContainer(const WayPointContainer& orig);
        virtual ~WayPointContainer();

        WayPointContainer& operator=(const WayPointContainer& rhs);
        HHN::WayPoint& operator[](int idx) const;

        void Add(const HHN::WayPoint& arg);

        int Size() const;
        void Print() const;
};

#endif /* SRC_WAYPOINTCONTAINER_H_ */
```

Here is my WayPointContainer.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include "WayPointContainer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Default Konstruktor
WayPointContainer::WayPointContainer() {
    //Heap bereich ... new ... pContainer
    pContainer = new std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>;
}

//Destruktor
WayPointContainer::~WayPointContainer() {} //TODO

//Copy Konstruktor
WayPointContainer::WayPointContainer(const WayPointContainer& orig) {
    pContainer = orig.pContainer;
}

WayPointContainer& WayPointContainer::operator=(const WayPointContainer& rhs) {
    if(&rhs == this) {
        return *this;
    }
    if ( pContainer != rhs.pContainer) {
        pContainer = rhs.pContainer;
    }
    return *this;
}

HHN::WayPoint& WayPointContainer::operator[](int idx) const {*
    //invalid initialization of reference of type 'HHN::WayPoint&' from expression of type 'std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>'
    return pContainer[idx];
}

void WayPointContainer::Add(const HHN::WayPoint& arg) {
    pContainer->insert(pContainer->begin(), arg);
}

int WayPointContainer::Size() const {
    int i = pContainer->size();
    return i;
}

void WayPointContainer::Print() const {
    for (auto waypoint = pContainer->begin(); waypoint != pContainer->end(); ++waypoint) {
        cout << waypoint->Name();
    }
}
```

The method i am struggling with:

```
HHN::WayPoint& WayPointContainer::operator[](int idx) const {*
    //invalid initialization of reference of type 'HHN::WayPoint&' from expression of type 'std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>'
    return pContainer[idx];
}
```

The Code i implemented there got the invalid initialization error described above.

So i expect to use the []-operator as described at the top but right now its not implemented or implemented with an error.

(I am also missing the Destructor for the vector "pContainer" inside the destructor of the WayPointContainer. So if thats something you know feel free to add it but thats not my question just a bonus.)

If you want i can also provide the code i got for the WayPoint class and   my main.cpp i use to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear about the immediate problem in your operator implementation

> ```
> invalid initialization of reference of type 'HHN::WayPoint&' from expression of type 'std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>'
> ```

`pContainer[idx]` dereferences `pContainer` with an offset of `idx`, thus the result is of type `std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>`.

There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. You either dereference the pointer and apply `idx` on it:

   ```
   return (*pContainer)[idx];
   ```
2. You don't use a pointer to hold your `std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>` class member at all (recommended solution):

   ```
   class WayPointContainer {
        private:
            std::vector<HHN::WayPoint> container;
        // ...
   };
   ```

   In that case you won't need to deal with memory de-/allocation for the pointer, and can simply write your operator overload as

   ```
   HHN::WayPoint& WayPointContainer::operator[](int idx) const {
        return container[idx];
   }
   ```

Comment: Well Thanks i guess i knew its probably super obvious and such but i just started C++ and couldn't figure it out. It took me over 10 hours just to get so far. I still mess pointer and references up a lot. The header files were given to me so i didn't want to change them.

Comment: @Saturas _"The header files were given to me so i didn't want to change them."_ Well, if they were given to you by your teacher, they must be either incompetent or just sadistic.